# Google Sheets- Trying to assign a script to an image to create a button

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I made the script using a macro recorder, and got the following:

[image: Script]

When I try to add it to a button, using the script name "bench" it returns an error telling me it can't find the script. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome. The script name is `Benchchange()`. "bench" is merely the name of the script file.

Comment: I tried changing the name and it didn't work. I then tried an entirely new button, still nothing

Comment: ** EDIT ** I got it to work!!!! Removed the semi colon after the last bracket! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of scripting. ;)